# ERROR: could not extend file "pg_tblspc/4815857/PG_11_201809051/16321": No space left on device

Tags: postgresql

My `postgres table occupied 100% memory` and want to truncate it.

When I USE `TRUNCATE TABLE TABLE_NAME` statement it gives be below Error:

> ERROR:  could not extend file
>   "pg_tblspc/4815857/PG_11_201809051/16321": No space left on device
>   HINT:  Check free disk space.

So I tried `DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME` statement which doesn't free the used space.

How can I force the truncate?

Comment: why don't you run `vacuum` after `delete from` to reclaim the space ?

Comment: @SvetlinZarev Don't you need additional space to perform `vacuum full`? AFAIK it does something like a fresh copy of table, swaps them and drops old one.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev VACUUM table_name;  gives me same error of "No space left on device"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TRUNCATE` needs to create a new (empty) file for the table, which probably causes your problem. You can `DROP` the table and recreate it.

Another, more cumbersome way would be

```
DELETE FROM table_name;
VACUUM table_name;  -- no FULL!
```

While `VACUUM` normally does not shrink the table, it will truncate emply pages off the end of the table. If the table is empty, that would remove all pages.