# How to avoid space issue during query execution in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

This is in continuation of one of my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58409824/unable-to-improve-query-performance-in-postgresql) which was about performance. But this time I got an error message. I am just trying to join 9 tables.

Please note that am able to join 8 out of 9 tables within 30 seconds. But the last `measurement` which is huge in number (4779657 records). It was taking long time due to the same.

At the end, I had the below error message and couldn't get the output.

I did refer this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57568013/error-could-not-extend-file-pg-tblspc-4815857-pg-11-201809051-16321-no-space) but not sure how to use this here

> ERROR:  could not extend file "base/17776/84170.71": No space left on device
>   HINT:  Check free disk space.

But am running this on a server

Please find below the query

```
DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW IF EXISTS cdm.dummy CASCADE;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW cdm.dummy as
select
f.person_id,f.gender_concept_id,f.year_of_birth,f.race_concept_id,f.ethnicity_concept_id,
a.visit_occurrence_id,a.visit_concept_id,a.visit_start_datetime,a.visit_end_datetime,a.admitting_source_concept_id,a.discharge_to_concept_id,
b.condition_concept_id,b.condition_start_datetime,b.condition_end_datetime,b.condition_type_concept_id,
c.measurement_concept_id,c.measurement_datetime,c.value_as_number,c.value_as_concept_id,c.unit_concept_id,
d.drug_concept_id,d.drug_exposure_start_datetime,d.drug_exposure_end_datetime,d.drug_type_concept_id,d.quantity,
e.procedure_concept_id,e.procedure_datetime,e.procedure_type_concept_id,
g.observation_concept_id,g.observation_datetime,g.value_as_number as "observation_value_as_num", g.value_as_string as "observation_value_as_string",
h.observation_period_start_date,h.observation_period_end_date,
i.death_datetime,i.cause_concept_id
from cdm.visit_occurrence a
left outer join 
cdm.condition_occurrence b
on a.person_id = b.person_id and a.visit_occurrence_id = b.visit_occurrence_id
left outer join 
cdm.drug_exposure d
on a.person_id = d.person_id and a.visit_occurrence_id = d.visit_occurrence_id
left outer join 
cdm.procedure_occurrence e
on a.person_id = e.person_id and a.visit_occurrence_id = e.visit_occurrence_id
left outer join 
cdm.person f
on a.person_id = f.person_id 
left outer join
cdm.observation g
on a.person_id = g.person_id and a.visit_occurrence_id = g.visit_occurrence_id
left outer join
cdm.observation_period h
on a.person_id = h.person_id
left outer join
cdm.death i
on a.person_id = i.person_id
left outer join 
cdm.measurement c
on a.person_id = c.person_id and a.visit_occurrence_id = c.visit_occurrence_id
```

Comment: You are not executing a query, you are running a ddl statement. Before running the DDL statement you need to make sure that you have enough space available. However if you run into this type of problem it is questionable that you have enough disk space configured for your postgres instance.

Comment: You mean to say that, if I don't create the `view`, then I may not encounter this error?

Comment: No, what i'm saying is you don't run a query. You create new database object. If you create new database objects, you need to make sure that you have enough space in the corresponding filesystem.

Comment: Hi, Do you know how can I get the `free disk space` in my filesystem for a db? Currently when I executed the below query, it only gives the size `SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('dbname'))` which is 62GB

Comment: That is the current size of your database, but what you are interested in is how much free space you have. Assuming you are linux, cd to your data directory and do a 'df -k .', this should tell you how much is used and how much is free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement creates a kind of table in the database (that's what the “materialized” means). Such an object requires space, and you do not have enough free space.

Since you are running out of space with file `84170.71` and each segment is 1GB in size, you have less than 72GB free disk space in the file system, which is not enough.

Comment: But the same query should run just for select clause without `materialized view`. Right?

Comment: That cannot be guaranteed. If `measurement` is large and PostgreSQL chooses to perform a merge join, it might need to sort the table and could run out of disk space for temporary files doing so. You'll have to try it. Maybe check the execution plan first.